# How to determine which server you are on when running in a Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

Our company now has a Sql Cluster consisting of two different Sql Servers. This works fine.

The difficulty, however, is knowing which server you are on. For the purpose of making sure that an SP is on Prod (and not on Test) we often do a check on which server the sql code is currently running on.  However, with a Cluster, the server's name can change, depending on which server is the is.

This is how we are currently doing it: `if @@SERVERNAME in ('SQLServer1','SQLServer2')`

This is what we would like to do so we are not hardcoding Server names:

`if @@SERVERNAME = 'SqlCluster'`

Any suggestions?  This is on Sql Server 2022

Comment: you can create a function like FN_AM_I_IN_PRODUCTION that returns something on one server but something else on test server. I would say in general, if you need to check, you already doing things wrongly :D

Comment: `select isnull((select cluster_name from sys.dm_hadr_cluster), @@SERVERNAME)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-cluster-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current

Comment: @Charlieface, If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sys.dm_hadr_cluster`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-cluster-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) management view.

```
select isnull(
  (select cluster_name from sys.dm_hadr_cluster),
  @@SERVERNAME
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs and considerations, you could set up extended properties in your environments; adding with `sp_addextendedproperty` and querying with `sys.extended_properties` or `fn_listextendedproperty`. You will still need some "hard coding", but this binds to a user defined data context, rather than a hardware architectural context.

There are other methods you could use that similarly involve putting data in a schema, including the `FN_AM_I_IN_PRODUCTION` suggestion from comments.